# What is the alternative for searchDisplayController in iOS 8?

Tags: ios8, deprecated, searchdisplaycontroller

This morning I changed my app's deployment target to 8.0. Unfortunately, searchDisplayController is deprecated in iOS 8.0.

My question is what is the alternative for searchDisplayController if I want my app be able to continue work on both iOS 7.x and 8.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative is UISearchController. If you set your Deployment Target to ios 7.x in the project file it will still work on iOS7

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISearchController